# Opengauss docker version build cannot run

Tags: docker, open-gauss

Today I want to build opengauss, because the database is too restrictive to the software system, so I chose the docker version.

I tried the latest version and the `3.0.0` version; but after the two versions of the image are downloaded, during execution, I always encounter that the service in the docker container hangs when connecting through the external database ide, and the log is pulled out to see this:

> [2022-09-12 08:48:43.955][179][][gs_ctl]: done [2022-09-12
> 08:48:43.955][179][][gs_ctl]: server started (/var/lib/opengauss/data)
> GS_DB = omm Execute SQL: gsql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username omm
> --password Xhhk##78 --dbname postgres --set db=omm --set passwd=Xhhk##78 CREATE DATABASE NOTICE: The encrypted password
> contains MD5 ciphertext, which is not secure. CREATE ROLE ALTER ROLE
>
> Execute SQL: gsql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username omm --password
> Xhhk##78 --dbname postgres --set db=omm --set passwd=Xhhk##78 --set
> user=gaussdb ERROR: role "gaussdb" already exists

Has anyone encountered this problem? Is there a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try  changed from the openGauss 3.0.0 image to the latest version of the latest image, specified the persistence path, and executed it again.